# What music was Kaori "playing" in the roof of the hospital in episode 21?

Tags: music, your-lie-in-april

In the scene on the roof of the hospital, in episode 21, Kaori starts mimicking playing a violin (around minute 10):

[image: Kaori mimicking playing a violin, around 10:53, episode 21]

I tried to find out what music she was playing, but [ANN's page on the anime](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/anime.php?id=16108) does not list the music (at least yet).

**What music is this, and who is its author?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is "Saint-Saëns, Camille Introduction + Rondo Capriccioso". It was also used in Episode 4, when Kousei and Kaori perform together for the first time.

I believe the segment we hear here begins around the time that Kaori starts playing the violin again after stopping for Kousei. If you remember, she encouraged him to start again. We hear a lot of Kaori's and Kousei's thoughts during this time, where she wants to join him in the journey to being a musician. To struggle together no matter how dark the road ahead is. She is most likely trying to bring back Kousei's memory of the struggle they faced together on that stage, and encourage him again to continue.

[Here](https://youtu.be/Q0ajM7aL-Vc?t=3m56s) is a version of it on YouTube.

Comment: Nice! It's from around minute 4 in the video you link to. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I think it is Introduction et Rondo Capriccioso by Camille Saint-Saëns

Comment: Could you add a link to a sample of that piece so the OP can see if it sounds right, and possibly point out some story justification for why it makes sense that this is the piece (if appropriate)? That would improve this answer; it's a bit sparse right now.